# XHTML Validation

Tags: html, xhtml

I am running my XHTML file through W3C validation and an error is coming up. However, I am unable to understand the error - it says, "No p element in scope but a p end tag seen".

Can some with fresh eyes see it?

Here is my code:

```
 <div id="mainBody">
             <div id="text">
                 <p>
                     <img src="images/billyGraham.png" alt="Billy Graham">
                     <blockquote>
                     Billy Graham:<br><br>
                     Is it not arrogance or narrow-mindedness to claim that there is only one way of salvation or that the way we follow is the right way? I think not. After all, do we fault a pilot for being narrow-minded when he follows the instrument panel [while] landing in a rainstorm? No, we want him to remain narrowly focused!
                     </blockquote>
                 </p>   
             </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `blockquote` element can't be inside a `P` element. It's invalid HTML. Although if you've tested in your target browsers and there's no issues I wouldn't worry too much, validation is just a guideline and shouldn't be taken too literally (IMO)

Comment: I appreciate your response.